# VS Code setting for Python Black to automatically give arguments a new line when defining a function

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-black

Is there a setting in VS Code that automatically puts each argument in a function definition to a new line? I am using black, and if there are enough arguments that the line length is greater than 79 characters then each argument is given a new line, but if the line length is less than 79 then the arguments stay on the same line. I would like a setting that automatically puts each argument on a new line.

What I have:

```
def func(arg1: str, arg2: int) -> int:
```

What I want:

```
def func(
    arg1: str,
    arg2: int
) -> int:
```

Comment: @rioV8 if then what? also, they said they're using black? quoting the docs "_Black is the uncompromising Python code formatter._" I'll wager what's being asked here is not possible.

Comment: @rioV8 both sides can do better. the question asker, and the question reader. the stronger has the option to help the weaker. I've edited.

Comment: @starball if I need to guess I most likely guess wrong, if the asker creates ambiguity I can't solve it